# How do you push the updated Postgres Docker image after Flyway runs in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, flyway

I have a docker-compose project where I use Flyway and Postgres Docker images to populate the Postgres database.  This works fine and I can connect to the database.  However I want to publish the database docker image for others to use in my organization without them needed to run the docker-compose.